# How to play DRM content using native WebOS player

Tags: webos

We are trying to play video content using native WebOS player and com.webos.service.drm service. The goal is to play at least some DRM content (dash+widevine or hls+widevine). Clear content works fine, but DRM content stucks completely, and no diagnostic messages appear.

The same result happens on WebOS 3.4, 4.4, and 6.0. Is there any working example of DRM content playback?

Our code is given below.

```
var appId = "com.zodiac.app";

// Define DRM Type
var drmType = "widevine";

function webos_request(service, params)
{
    var caller = arguments.callee.caller.name;

    console.log("REQ: %s: %s %s", caller, service, JSON.stringify(params))
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        webOS.service.request(service, Object.assign({}, params, {
            onSuccess: function (result) { console.log("REQ SUCCESS: %s: %s %s: %s", caller, service, params.method, JSON.stringify(result)); resolve(result) },
            // onFailure: function (result) {
            //     console.log("[" + result.errorCode + "] " + result.errorText);
            //     reject()
            // }

            onFailure: function (result) { console.error("REQ ERROR: %s: %s %s: %s",   caller, service, params.method, JSON.stringify(result)); reject(result) }
        }))
    });
}


function webos_subscribe(service, params, method)
{
    var caller = arguments.callee.caller.name;
    var completed = false
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        params.parameters = params.parameters || {}
        params.parameters.subscribe = true;

        console.log("SUB: %s: %s %s", caller, service, JSON.stringify(params))

        webOS.service.request("luna://com.webos.service.drm", Object.assign({}, params, {
            onSuccess: function (result) { // Subscription Callback

                if (!completed) {
                    completed = true;

                    if (result.subscribed) {
                        console.log("SUB: %s: %s: SUCCESS", caller, service)
                        resolve(result)
                    }
                    else {
                        console.error("SUB: %s: %s: FAILED", caller, service)
                        reject();
                    }

                }
                else
                    method(result)
            },
            onFailure: function (result) {
                console.error("SUB: %s: %s: onFailure", caller, service, result)
                // console.log('Player.subscribeLicensingError onFailure: ' + '[' + result.errorCode + '] ' + result.errorText);
                completed = true;
                reject()
            }
        }));
    });
}

function unloadDrmClient(clientId)
{
    webos_request("luna://com.webos.service.drm",
    {
        method:"unload",
        parameters: {
            "clientId": result.clientId
        }
    });
}

function loadDrmClient()
{
    return webos_request( "luna://com.webos.service.drm", {
            method:"load",
            parameters: {
                "drmType": drmType,
                "appId": appId
            }})
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log("DRM Client is loaded successfully. %s", JSON.stringify(result));

                document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
                    if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
                        unloadDrmClient(result.clientId)
                    }
                })

                return result.clientId
            })
}


function sendRightInformation(clientId, url, la_url) {
    var msgId;

    // Message format for widevine
    var msg = [
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>',
        '<WidevineCredentialsInfo xmlns="http://www.smarttv-alliance.org/DRM/widevine/2012/protocols/">',
        '<ContentURL>' + url + '</ContentURL>',
        '<DeviceID></DeviceID>',
        '<StreamID></StreamID>',
        '<ClientIP></ClientIP>',
        '<DRMServerURL>' + la_url + '</DRMServerURL>',
        '<DRMAckServerURL></DRMAckServerURL>',
        '<DRMHeartBeatURL></DRMHeartBeatURL>',
        '<DRMHeartBeatPeriod>0</DRMHeartBeatPeriod>',
        '<UserData></UserData>',
        '<Portal></Portal>',
        '<StoreFront></StoreFront>',
        '<BandwidthCheckURL></BandwidthCheckURL>',
        '<BandwidthCheckInterval></BandwidthCheckInterval>',
        '</WidevineCredentialsInfo>',
    ].join("")

    // Message type for widevine
    var msgType = "application/widevine+xml";

    // Unique ID of DRM system
    var drmSystemId = "urn:dvb:casystemid:19156";

    return webos_request( "luna://com.webos.service.drm", {
            method:"sendDrmMessage",
            parameters: {
                "clientId": clientId,
                "msgType": msgType,
                "msg": msg,
                "drmSystemId": drmSystemId
            }})
            .then( function (result) {
                // DRM API does not return the msgId, resultCode, resultMsg for Widevine type.
                console.log("sendDrmMessage succeeded. %s", JSON.stringify(result));
                return
            });
}

function subscribeLicensingError(clientId, msgId)
{
    return webos_subscribe("luna://com.webos.service.drm", {
        method:"getRightsError",
        parameters: {
            "clientId": clientId
        }},
        function (result) { // Subscription Callback
            var contentId = result.contentId;
            if (contentId == msgId) {
                if ( 0 == result.errorState) {
                    console.log("No license");
                    // Do something for error handling
                }
                else if ( 1 == result.errorState) {
                    console.log("Invalid license");
                    // Do something for error handling
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Unknown errorState: %s", JSON.stringify(result));
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("skip notification %s", JSON.stringify(result));
            }
        });
}

var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');

function playback()
{
    var config = {

        'dash+wv': {
            type: "application/dash+xml",
            mediaTransportType: "WIDEVINE",
            url: 'https://bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/content/art-of-motion_drm/mpds/11331.mpd',
            la_url: 'https://widevine-proxy.appspot.com/proxy'
        },

        'hls+wv': {
            type: "application/x-mpegURL",
            mediaTransportType: "HLS",
            url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/shaka-demo-assets/angel-one-widevine-hls/hls.m3u8',
            la_url: 'https://cwip-shaka-proxy.appspot.com/no_auth'
        },

        'mp4': {
            type: "video/mp4",
            url: "https://jsoncompare.org/LearningContainer/SampleFiles/Video/MP4/Sample-MP4-Video-File-Download.mp4"
        },

        'hls': {
            type: "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl",
            url: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8",
        },

        'dash': {
            type: "application/dash+xml",
            url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/shaka-demo-assets/bbb-dark-truths/dash.mpd'
        }
    }

    var stream = config['hls+wv']

    var prepare

    if (stream.la_url) {
        prepare = loadDrmClient()
        .then( function(id) {
            subscribeLicensingError(id, undefined);

            document.body.addEventListener("unload", function() {
                webOS.service.request("luna://com.webos.service.drm", {
                    method:"unload",
                    parameters: { "clientId": id },
                    onSuccess: function (result) {
                        console.log("DRM Client is unloaded successfully.");
                    },
                    onFailure: function (result) {
                        console.log("[" + result.errorCode + "] " + result.errorText);
                        // Do something for error handling
                    }
                });
            })
            return sendRightInformation(id, stream.url, stream.la_url).then( function () { return id; })
        })
    }
    else {
        prepare = Promise.resolve()
    }

    return prepare.then( function (id) {
        var type = stream.type

        if (stream.la_url) {

            var options = {
                mediaTransportType: stream.mediaTransportType,
                option: {
                    drm: {
                        type: drmType,
                        clientId: id,
                    }
                }
            };

            console.log("Options: %s", JSON.stringify(options));
            var mediaOption = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(options));
            type += ';mediaOption=' + mediaOption;
        }

        console.log("open url: %s", stream.url)
        console.log("type    : %s", type)
        var source = document.createElement("source");
        source.setAttribute('src', stream.url);
        source.setAttribute('type', type);

        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(event) {
            console.log("loadedmetadata %O", event)
        });

        video.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
            console.error('error', e);
        });

        video.addEventListener('stalled', function(e) {
            console.log('stalled', e);
        });

        video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
            console.log('[Device_Webos_Player] loadeddata');
        });

        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
            console.log('[Device_Webos_Player] loadedmetadata');
        });

        video.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
            console.log('[Device_Webos_Player] canplay');
        });

        video.addEventListener('durationchange', function() {
            console.log('[Device_Webos_Player] durationchange: ' + video.duration);
        });

        video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
            console.log('[Device_Webos_Player] timeupdate: ' + video.currentTime);
        }, { once: true});


        video.appendChild(source);
        // video.load()
        video.play()
    })
}

playback()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the idea is [see [here](https://developer.lge.com/community/forums/RetrieveForumContent.dev?detailContsId=FC12082054&sMenuId=53&contsTypeCode=QUE&prodTypeCode=TV)]

- MPEG-DASH streaming is officially not supported on the webOS TV.
- HLS plays AES-128 DRM only in public version
- HTML5 EME/MSE can use both widevine and playready

See "Streaming Protocol & DRM Combination" [here](https://webostv.developer.lge.com/discover/specifications/supported-media-formats/)

Comment: We have been using shaka player to play DASH + Widevine on webOS 3.5+ TVs and it works fine.

Comment: Indeed, we turn to use shaka as well. Tried to play using native webos facilities, just to compare resource consumption and features available. And it appeared to be very limited

Comment: Did you try dash.js on LG by any chance? If so, what was your experience?

Comment: It might be too late, but nevertheless. We did a test run with dash.js and it seems to work fine. Also it has some advantages over shaka with respect to dash streams with time discrepancies. I mean the case when timeline in manifest does not directly match with the timeline in segments (out customers prefer tune time over correctness). In shaka this is problematic, and it reacts with blackscreen or extra segments downloading. While in dash.js we developed a workaround to persuade it to play that is available easily.